# Soap Webservice on Oracle 11.2: "Incorrect Input Doc/URL"

Tags: oracle, soap

I'm trying to define a webservice schema A of a given Oracle database of version 11.2.

I've granted this to the schema:

```
grant xdb_webservices to <schema A>
/

grant xdb_webservices_over_http to <schema A>
/
```

When I access a given function in schema A I get this output for wsdl:

```
<soap:Envelope><soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode><faultstring>Error processing input</faultstring><detail><OracleErrors>
    Incorrect Input Doc/URL
  </OracleErrors></detail></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

I have a schema B on the same database where webservices work OK. When I create the same function in schema B wsdl looks ok. So there must be some subtle difference between those two schemas. No difference in grants as far as I can tell. Any ideas what else to check?

Answer (score 0):

Oh no! It did work - I was just too dumb!

I first accessed the first schema's wsdl URL (https:///orawsv//?wsdl) entering username and password.
When I tried accessing the second schema's WSDL I did this in another browser tab (within the same browser session) - and I was not asked for login info - it just used the one from the other tab.

So the solution is: start a new browser session and enter the URL again! :-)